# How do I dispose of gasoline?

Tags: garage, disposal

We've inherited a house with several gas (petrol) containers in the garage. I haven't tried using them because

1. I don't know how old they are.
2. I don't know what oil/gas mixture they have.

They've been sitting around for over a year now, and I want to get rid of them. What's the responsible way of disposing of them?

Comment: This was covered on Mechanics SE: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/504/26

Answer (score 8):

Your local fire department should take them off your hands and dispose of them properly (in an environmentally safe manner) and safely.

I say the above, as I recently wanted to dispose of some old engine coolant in a responsible manner and didn't know where I could take it for disposal, so I went to our local fire station to ask them, they pointed me in the right direction and additionally informed me for future reference they take and dispose of petrol (gas).

Answer (score 6):

Contact your local council (or equivalent) to see if they have a safe disposal site.

Another alternative could be to contact a local mechanic or scrap yard to see how they dispose of petrol from the cars they deal with. You never know they might offer to take it off your hands for you.

Comment: This was going to be my answer; any garage that does oil changes and/or fuel system work has to be able to dispose of hazardous wastes by the barrelful every day, so you can bet they have a contact for pickup/disposal. They may charge you a few bucks to take it off your hands, but better than getting fined hundreds or thousands by your local gov't for illegal dumping.